# how to get the path of upload images in Sparkjava framework?

Tags: java, spark-java

In my project, I upload the images through the method in [upload method](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sparkjava/fjO64BP1UQw/CsxdNVz7qrAJ). 
The project directory is :

```
Project
   |---src/main/java
   |---src/main/resources
                   |---static
                          |---css
                               |---default.css
   |---upload
         |---1.jpg
         |---2.jpg
```

The view page render by freemarker. In my showimage.ftl file, the img tag `<img src="...">`, how to define the uploaded image path in src.

If put the upload image in the `src/main/resources`, I can use the method `staticFileLocation` to access, but I can't upload the images to the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a stream of the file, and send a raw response.
Just modify the code to get the a flexible path depending on your request object.

```
try {
   String path = "upload/1.jpg";
   Path p = Paths.get(path);

   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(p.toFile());

   res.raw().setContentType(Files.probeContentType(p));
   res.raw().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + p.getFileName());

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int len;
   while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      res.raw().getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
   }

   String result = IOUtils.toString(is);
   is.close();
   return result.trim();
} catch (Exception e) { // handle the exceptions the way you want
   logger.error("Error while getting resource", e);
   res.status(500);
   return "";
}
```

Comment: You solution is not very ideal. You can't be converting your stream to a string, storing in memory, just to send it to the client. Why not just stream it to the Outputstream instead to avoid memory issues?